# ScreenShot in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I am having two control image view and canvas.
Over image i am drawing rectangle.While taking screenshot i am only getting image not the rectangle.

Using below code i am getting black image

```
int Width = (int)canvas1.RenderSize.Width;
            int Height = (int)canvas1.RenderSize.Height;
RenderTargetBitmap renderTargetBitmap =
new RenderTargetBitmap(Width, Height, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
            renderTargetBitmap.Render(canvas1);
            PngBitmapEncoder pngImage = new PngBitmapEncoder();
            pngImage.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(renderTargetBitmap));
            using (Stream fileStream = File.Create(filePath))
            {
                pngImage.Save(fileStream);

            }
```

if i am replacing canvas with image only image is coming.
How to take screenshot containing both the controls ?

Comment: I hard-coded everything, canvas with image, and rectangle over image. Your code fine for me inside a Button.Click.

Comment: are u able to take screenshot ?

Comment: I am able to save image with rectangle.

Comment: please send me code and screenshot if possible in a answer section

Comment: thanku..its done ..above code is working

Answer (score 1):

have a `no-op` after the `render` call for the render to be completed before taking the screenshot.
Also am assuming you are able to view the drawn rectangle in the viewport
and it is only not appearing in the screenshot. If not make sure the color of the rectangle is distinct against the image background.

```
renderTargetBitmap.Render(canvas1);
//no-op for rendering to complete before taking screenshot.
_dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, new Action(() => { }));
//screenshot code here.
```

Comment: there is imageview over which canvas is there..i am drawing rectangle over canvas. only image it is taking in screenshot..above solution didnt work for me